# Replace if with for in progress bar

Tags: bash

I have an if-testing construct for a bash-progress bar:

```
progress_bar () {
PROGRESS=`expr $( cat $CONTROL_FILE ) - 100 | tr "-" "\r"`
clear
    if [ "$PROGRESS" -eq 10 ]
    then
    echo -n "$PROGRESS % [#         ] "
    fi
    if [ $PROGRESS -eq 20 ]
    then
    echo -n "$PROGRESS % [##        ] "
    fi
    if [ $PROGRESS -eq 30 ]
    then
    echo -n "$PROGRESS % [###       ] "
    fi
    if [ $PROGRESS -eq 40 ]
    then
            echo -n "$PROGRESS % [####      ] "
    fi
    if [ $PROGRESS -eq 50 ]
    then
            echo -n "$PROGRESS % [#####     ] "
    fi
    if [ $PROGRESS -eq 60 ]
    then
            echo -n "$PROGRESS % [######    ] "
    fi
    if [ $PROGRESS -eq 70 ]
    then
            echo -n "$PROGRESS % [#######   ] "
    fi
    if [ $PROGRESS -eq 80 ]
    then
            echo -n "$PROGRESS % [########  ] "
    fi
    if [ $PROGRESS -eq 90 ]
    then
            echo -n "$PROGRESS % [######### ] "
    fi
    if [ $PROGRESS -eq 100 ]
    then
            echo "$PROGRESS % [##########]"
    fi}
```

It works well: A "#" will be added each time when +10 are counted. My question is: Is there a way to make this look more beautiful? Like a for-loop or something else?

Thanks

Comment: use dialog or zenity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
progress_bar () {
    local percent hashes
    hashes='##########'
    percent=$(<"$CONTROL_FILE")
    printf '\r%d %% [%-10s] ' $((100 - percent)) "${hashes:percent/10}"
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank to all of you for your answers, I'll choose this solution because it's the shortest one. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
progress_bar() {
    local progress n bar
    progress=$(expr $(<"$CONTROL_FILE") - 100 | tr "-" "\r")
    clear
    n=$(( $progress / 10 ))
    if (( $progress > 0 )); then
        bar=$(printf "%${n}s" " " | tr " " "#")
    fi
    printf "%s %% [%s]" "$progress" "$bar"
    (( $progress >= 100 )) && echo              # put newline when done
}
```

- `printf "%${n}s" " " | tr " " "#"` repeats a whitespace `$n` times, then
  relace them with `#`s of the same count.
- As it is not recommended to use uppercases for user's variables, I've
  changed `PROGRESS` to `progress`.